# memory used: std::list v.s. std::forward_list

Tags: list

Because list have one more pointer(previous pointer) than forward_list, so if they both hold the same number of element, i.e. 1<<30, list will use almost 1/3 more memory. Right?

Then if I repeat calling resize larger and larger, forward_list must be able to resize much larger than list.

Test code:

```
#include<forward_list>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    using namespace std;
    typedef list<char> list_t;
    //typedef forward_list<char> list_t;
    list_t l;
    list_t::size_type i = 0;
    try{
        while(1){
            l.resize(i += (1<<20));
            cerr<<i<<" ";
        }
    }
    catch(...){
        cerr<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To my surprise, when the process is killed, they have almost the same size ...
Anybody could interpret it?

Comment: How are you measuring the memory usage of each list?

Comment: In this code I don't measure it. My computer have 3.78G memory in total. I just run the code respectively till the process is killed and check the value of i. I think the value of i should have large difference.

Comment: +1 for highlighting the new c++11 container std::forward_list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use C++ forward\_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25472527/when-to-use-c-forward-list)

Comment: A later duplicate question is clearer and has better answers.

Comment: @Raedwald I don't think they are duplicate. That question is more about the usage and why , while mine more about how to measure and the real performances.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should find that with better memory sniffing that your initial hypothesis that a `std::list<T>` will consume three times as much energy is correct.  On my Windows machine, I whipped up a quick memory usage program using [GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Here is the core of my program:

```
int main()
{
    size_t initMemory = MemoryUsage();
    std::list<unsigned char> linkedList;

    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
        linkedList.push_back(i % 256);
    size_t linkedListMemoryUsage = MemoryUsage() - initMemory;

    std::forward_list<unsigned char> forwardList;
    for (int i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
        forwardList.push_front(i % 256);
    size_t forwardListMemoryUsage = MemoryUsage() - linkedListMemoryUsage - initMemory;

    std::cout << "Bytes used by Linked List: " << linkedListMemoryUsage << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Bytes used by Forward List: " << forwardListMemoryUsage << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Results when running it under release build:

```
#define ITERATIONS 128
Bytes used by Linked List: 24576
Bytes used by Forward List: 8192
8192 * 3 = 24576
```

Here's a quote from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/forward_list/) that even says that there should be noticeable memory difference between the two containers.

> The main design difference between a forward_list container and a list
>   container is that the first keeps internally only a link to the next
>   element, while the latter keeps two links per element: one pointing to
>   the next element and one to the preceding one, allowing efficient
>   iteration in both directions, but consuming additional storage per
>   element and with a slight higher time overhead inserting and removing
>   elements. forward_list objects are thus more efficient than list
>   objects, although they can only be iterated forwards.

Using the resize function on the lists, as you do in the posted code, the memory difference was even more pronounced with `std::list<T>` consuming four times as much memory.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I will test on linux as well. Thank you!

Comment: It does not make sense to me why `list` would take 3x as much memory as `forward_list`. As you quoted `list` keeps 2 links (aka pointers), while `forward_list` keeps one link. So I would expect each node in `list<int>` to be 192 bytes while each node in `forward_list<int>` to be 128 bytes, which is only 1/3 larger, not 3x.

Answer (score 11):

I know the question is 4 years old, but the accepted answer makes no sense (as Justin Raymond pointed out).

Nick Babcock's approach is imprecise, as the number of elements is too low; there is always some overhead on the heap, that you will measure as well.

To show this, I used a bigger data type and more elements (4096):
On `g++ 6.2.1` and `linux x64` `sizeof(void*) = 8` and `sizeof (bigDataType_t) = 800` (`bigData_t` is `long[100]`).

So what do we expect? Each type of list has to store the actual data on the heap; `std::list` stores 2 pointers per link (backward and forward), `std::forward_list` just one (forward).

Expected memory for `std::list`:
`4096 x 800 + 2 x 8 x 4096 = 3,342,336 bytes`

Actual memory for `std::list`: `3,415,040 bytes`

Expected memory for `std::forward_list`:
`4096 x 800 + 1 x 8 x 4096 = 3,309,568 bytes`

Actual memory for `std::forward_list`: `3,382,272 bytes`

I used [Massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) to get the heap usage of the programs.

As we can see, the numbers fit quite well. When using big data types, the memory for the extra pointer doesn't make much difference!

When using `char` as datatype (as OP), the expected and actual memory footprint don't fit too well, most likely because of some overhead. However, there is no factor 3 for memory consumption.

`std::list: Expected 69,632 bytes, actual: 171,008 bytes`

`std::forward_list: Expected 36,864 bytes, actual: 138,240 bytes`

My code:

```
#include <list>
#include <forward_list>

struct bigData_t {
    long foo[100];
};
typedef bigData_t myType_t;
// typedef char myType_t;

int main()
{
#ifdef USE_FORWARD_LIST
    std::forward_list<myType_t> linkedList;
#else
    std::list<myType_t> linkedList;
#endif
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        myType_t bigData;
        linkedList.push_front(bigData);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is it that in both the list and forward_list the container uses about 75 thousand bytes more than expected? There must be something about the container I don't understand, even if it kept the size and a couple of extra pointers this should still amount to less than 50 bytes extra, but an extra 75 thousand?

Comment: @Zebrafish Please note that I didn't measure the heap usage of the lists alone, but the heap usage of the whole program. There might be some overhead for program initialization or the like.