# Difference between list and forward_list performance?

Tags: c++, list, c++11, stl, forward-list

As with c++11 we have two types of list:

```
std::list<int> lst = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

std::forward_list<int> flst = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
```

As we know that the list is based on the doubly linked list and forward_list is based on the singly linked list.

How should we decide which one to used? Is there any performance benefit of any of the list above other?

Comment: For memory comparison, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545058/memory-used-stdlist-v-s-stdforward-list

Comment: [_"Compared to std::list this container provides more space efficient storage when bidirectional iteration is not needed._"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list). Thus, if you are already set on using a linked list, and if you don't need bidirectional iteration, choose `std::forward_list`, whereas if you need bidirectional iteration capacities, use `std::list`. But before making this decision, make sure to compare if you really want a linked list at all, of if a contiguous storage random-access `std::vector` or `std::array` could be a viable alternative.

Comment: @Azeem note that the accepted answer in that thread is very contrived (to the point of misleading), using a linked list for objects of 1 byte size (in which case the additional pointer in `std::list` will seem extremely memory costly). The non-accepted answer in the linked Q&A makes a more sound comparison.

Comment: The decision is simple. Never use either one. There's always a better data structure. Well, almost always. If you are facing the necessity of using a linked list, you are doing pretty esoteric stuff and SO isn't going to help you.

Comment: @n.m. I wouldn't go quite that far, but yes, of you answered every question about std list with "don't use std list" you'd have above a 99% accuracy rate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> How should we decide which one to used?

Decide if you need bidirectional iteration.  If forward iteration is good enough, use `std::forward_list`, unless you need to support C++ versions older than C++11, which may only have `std::list`.

> Is there any performance benefit of any of the list above other?

`std::forward_list` eliminates a pointer per node (with all the attendant benefits for the data cache and memory subsystem), while `std::list` provides constant-time iterator decrement.

But in practice, neither of these containers is as widely used as one might believe when attending computer science school.  The real performance of `std::vector` is superior for many applications, and its memory usage is always less.  More demanding applications requiring lists would do well to consider intrusive lists, which standard C++ does not provide.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [john-zwinck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4323/john-zwinck) said, if you have to use linked-lists, bear in mind the followings when making your decision:

`std::forward_list` doesn't have the modifiers functions operating at the end due to its nature:

> push_back,  pop_back, emplace_back

Furthermore, `std::forward_list` doesn't provide a `size` member function for more efficiency according to the `std::list`. `size` function of the `std::list` gives the number of elements in constant time by C++11. On the other hand, it requires some extra storage for the internal counter and this makes inserting and removing slightly less efficient. In order to attain the size of a `std::forward_list`, the distance algorithm can be used with `begin()` and `end()` functions but this operation takes linear time.

Comment: Do you have a source for the claim that the `::size()` member function was omitted from `std::forward_list` so its insertion and removal operations can be more efficient than `std::list`'s ? I always thought it was just an oversight, since I would expect the extra cost of repointing both forwards and backwards pointers to dominate the extra time `std::list` takes for modification operations...